# how do dynamic dependencies work in python setup.py?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools, setup.py

My package has some optional installs

```
# for extra 'cmd'
cmd_line_requirements = [
    'Click>=6.0'
]
```

The setup function defines this extra like so:

```
extras_require={
    'cmd': cmd_line_requirements,
},
```

and the entry_points are defined as follows:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'threedigrid=threedigrid.cli:main [cmd]',
    ],
},
```

When I install the package with pip

```
pip install --editable .
```

Click is not being installed but the entry_points.txt in my threedigrid.egg.info contains the following:

```
[console_scripts]
threedigrid = threedigrid.cli:main [cmd]
```

I am a bit puzzled by that because I would assume that the console script will only be generated if it the package is installed with the [cmd] option specified. `which threedigrid` yields

```
/home/<>/.virtualenvs/grid_test/bin/threedigrid
```

Am I misunderstanding how dynamic dependencies work?

Answer (score 2):

The entry points are always created but trying to run script `threedigrid` without `[cmd]` will result in `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound` exception:

> The 'Click' distribution was not found and is required by the application